Check if $\eta = -\frac{4xz}{x^2 + 1} \, dx + \frac{2y}{y^2 + 1} \, dy + \frac{2}{x^2 + 1} \, dz.$ is closed or not
I have problems with this k-form:
$$\eta = -\frac{4xz}{x^2 + 1} \, dx + \frac{2y}{y^2 + 1} \, dy + \frac{2}{x^2 + 1} \, dz.$$
apparently it is closed, but I can't figure out how that comes about. I do two procedures to check if it is closed or not.
I do
$$
\eta = -\frac{4xz}{x^2 + 1} \, dx + \frac{2y}{y^2 + 1} \, dy + \frac{2}{x^2 + 1} \, dz.
$$
To compute $d\eta$, we calculate:
$$
d\eta = d\left( -\frac{4xz}{x^2 + 1} \right) \wedge dx + d\left( \frac{2y}{y^2 + 1} \right) \wedge dy + d\left( \frac{2}{x^2 + 1} \right) \wedge dz.
$$
First term:
$$
d\left(-\frac{4xz}{x^2 + 1}\right) = \left(-\frac{4z}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{8x^2z}{(x^2 + 1)^2}\right) dx - \frac{4x}{x^2 + 1} dz.
$$
Second term:
$$
d\left(\frac{2y}{y^2 + 1}\right) = \frac{2 - 2y^2}{(y^2 + 1)^2} dy.
$$
Third term:
$$
d\left(\frac{2}{x^2 + 1}\right) = -\frac{4x}{(x^2 + 1)^2} dx.
$$
Substituting back:
$$
d\eta = \left[\left(-\frac{4z}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{8x^2z}{(x^2 + 1)^2}\right) dx - \frac{4x}{x^2 + 1} dz\right] \wedge dx
+ \frac{2 - 2y^2}{(y^2 + 1)^2} dy \wedge dy
+ \left(-\frac{4x}{(x^2 + 1)^2} dx \right) \wedge dz.
$$
Since $dy \wedge dy = 0$ and $dx \wedge dx = 0$:
$$
d\eta = -\frac{4x}{(x^2 + 1)^2} dx \wedge dz - \frac{4x}{x^2 + 1} dz \wedge dx.
$$
Using $dx \wedge dz = -dz \wedge dx$:
$$
d\eta = \left(-\frac{4x}{(x^2 + 1)^2} + \frac{4x}{x^2 + 1}\right) dx \wedge dz.
$$
Simplify:
$$
-\frac{4x}{(x^2 + 1)^2} + \frac{4x}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{-4x + 4x(x^2 + 1)}{(x^2 + 1)^2} = \frac{-4x + 4x^3 + 4x}{(x^2 + 1)^2} = \frac{4x^3}{(x^2 + 1)^2}.
$$
Thus:
$$
d\eta = \frac{4x^3}{(x^2 + 1)^2} dx \wedge dz.
$$
Since $d\eta \neq 0$, the form $\eta$ is not closed.
But my Professor says it is closed.
Any ideas who is right?

Are you sure the first term is not $-4xz/(1+x^2)^2$?

I don't understand your first approach. What do you mean by saying $\eta$ is open?

I mean it is not closed since its not exact by the first approach. And the term is $-\frac{4xz}{1+x^2}$

why you conclude it's not closed from the first approach?

It is not closed. I am also asking myself what on earth that first approach has to do with the question. The end result of the second approach looks correct.

@KurtG. I now removed it, but isn't that first approach related to the exactness of differential equations where one equation can only be exact if it is closed?

I don't know who told you that. The form $\omega=\frac{y,dx-x,dy}{x^2+y^2}$ is known to be closed but not exact. None of the partial derivatives you computed earlier is zero.

Interesting. Thanks Kurt!

Denote by $F$ the vector field associated to $\eta$:
$$F=\left(-\frac{4xz}{x^2 + 1}, \frac{2y}{y^2 + 1},\frac{2}{x^2 + 1} \right)=(F_x,F_y,F_z)$$
Compute the $\operatorname{curl}$:
\begin{align}\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z}&=0 \\
\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}&=-\frac{4x}{1+x^2}+\frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2}\neq 0\end{align}
Hence the form is not closed.
